# undefined local variable or method `act_as_votable' for User (call 'User.connection' to establish a connection):Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have installed the act_as_votable gem and followed the instructions by adding the gem to my gemfile,db migrate, added 'act as votable' to models and added methods in controller. 
I have also updated my index page to show the buttons however I get this error message when I load my page:

`` undefined local variable or method `act_as_votable' for User (call 'User.connection' to establish a connection):Class ``
 
Ive never seen this error before, i'm new to ruby...

here is my repo for ease of understanding: https://github.com/Angela-Inniss/hair-do

User model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable
  has_many :comments
  has_many :hairstyles
  has_many :saved_hairstyles
  act_as_votable
end
```

hairstyle model:

```
class Hairstyle < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user, optional: true
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :description, presence: true
  validates :category, presence: true
  act_as_votable
  mount_uploader :photo, PhotoUploader


end
```

hairstyle controller:

```
 def upvote
    @hairstyle = Hairstyle.find(params[:id])
    @hairstyle.upvote_from current_user
    redirect_to hairstyles_path
  end

  def downvote
    @hairstyle = Hairstyle.find(params[:id])
    @hairstyle.downvote_from current_user
    redirect_to hairstyles_path
  end
```

index.html.erb:

```
    <%= link_to like_hairstyle_path(hairstyle), class: 'like' method: :put do %>
      <i class="fa fa-heart">
      <span><%= hairstyle.get_upvotes.size %><span>
      </i>
    <%end %>

    <!--this is a link block- create the block and then add elements inside?-->
      <%= link_to like_hairstyle_path(hairstyle), class: 'like' method: :put do %>
      <i class="fa fa-heart">
      <span><%= hairstyle.get_downvotes.size %><span>
      </i>
    <%end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Notice what the error message says?

```
undefined local variable or method 'act_as_votable' for User (call 'User.connection' to establish a connection):Class
                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

It should be:

```
acts_as_votable
```

not:

```
act_as_votable
```

(You have it wrong in both `User` and `Hairstyle`.)

Comment: Hello I changed it to acts_as_votable and it still doesn't work. Ill post the error message when I am behind a computer again. Thank you in advance. Angela